# run function in pandas to create new column

Tags: python-3.x

I have this df:

```
df = {'Option': ["A", "B", "C"]}
```

I'm trying to create a new row, Identifier, that equals 1 if the value in the Option column equals "A". If not, the value in Identifier should return 0.

I created the following function to do this:

```
def trigger(row):
    if df['Option'] == "A":
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Here is what I tried for the Identifier column:

```
df['Identifier'] = df['Option'].apply(trigger, axis=1)
```

When I `print(df)`, I get the following error: TypeError: trigger() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

final df should look like this:

```
finaldf = {'Option': ["A", "B", "C"],
          'Identifier': [1,0,0]}
```

It seems relatively straightforward problem, but idk why it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

Your method does not work because you are not using the row in your trigger. Furthermore, you can do this entirely vectorized:

```
df['Identifier'] = 0 
df.loc[df.Option == 'A', 'Identifier'] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['Identifier'] = np.where(df.Option == 'A', 1,0)
```

For multiple conditions you might try

```
df["Identfier"] = np.where(df.Option.isin(["A", "B"]), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you know how to expand the equal statement with "or." I tried df['Identifier'] = np.where(df.Option == 'A' or 'B', 1,0), but I got this error: ValueError: "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."